# Definition of Hypothesis Testing in All of Statistics

Tags: hypothesis-testing, definition

In the book All of Statistics by Larry Wesserman, the author says "Let $X$ be a random variable and let $\mathcal{X}$ be the range of $X$. We test a hypothesis by finding an appropriate subset of outcomes $R \subset \mathcal{X}$ called the rejection region". Then the author proceeds to say that $X \in R \Rightarrow$ reject $H_0$, and usually a region $R$ is of the form $\{x: T(x) > c\}$, where $c$ is a critical value, and $T$ is a test statistic.

Could someone please help me understand how a random variable $X$ is an element in the region? I thought a random variable can take a range of values, and a hypothesis testing is applied on a collection of samples instead of a single one. If $X$ here means a set of values, then should the author use $X \subset R \Rightarrow$ reject $H_0$?

Update: @whuber's comment answers my question. The function $T$ in the definition of rejection region takes a set of values, which is exactly $X(\omega)$. This is also consistent with the statement that $R$ is a subset of the range of the random variable $X$.

Comment: The notation "$X\in R$" is shorthand for $X(\omega)\in R$ where $\omega$ is in the sample space.  The notation "$X\subset R$" makes little sense, because it implies $X$ is a set of real numbers, not a random variable.

Comment: '... how a random variable X is an element in the region?' I didn't understand. If $\bf X$ falls into the critical region of its range, then $\mathcal H_0$ is rejected. This is the basis of (non-randomized) test procedure.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what the problem is but maybe the following can help to get some intuition about flipping between the rejection region in the event space and the rejection region for a statistic: Think of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/365070/164061) geometric representation/motivation of the t-distribution. For a given hypothesis the rejection region is  a n-dimensional cone shape where n is the sample size. It can also be represented in terms of the t-statistic.

Comment: "and a hypothesis testing is applied on a collection of samples instead of a single one" does this conflict with the statements in the book?

Comment: @whuber it seems your comment helped OP clear the impending confusion. So, would you like to turn that an answer? OP could accept that.