Comparison of 2 groups with covariate
I compared 2 groups and found that their test scores are significantly different. However, I also found that they are significantly different in the mean age. I want to see if the scores between the groups are still significantly different, after removing the effect of age. The correlation between scores and age is very small, $r = 0.03$.
One option would be to use ANCOVA, but this is a bit outdated technique IMO.
My other option is to use a regression model, but I can't figure out the model, specifically what are my DVs and what is my IV.

To me a linear regression with your group variable and age as predictors sounds like a good choice (ANCOVA with group as the between-subject factor and age as a covariate is actually equivalent to such regression, just as ANOVA is equivalent to a regression with just the group predictor).

Many thanks to all the answers and the theoretical/Lexical discussion!

I agree with @Sointu's comment.
There is nothing "outdated" about ANCOVA. In what I see it's most often just approached through regression. The techniques aren't alternatives, at least not for your set-up.
Your outcome or response is test score and your predictors are age and your group variable. There is one outcome (DV, in your terminology) and two predictors (IV, in your terminology). If you're thinking that regression is predicting one independent variable from one or more dependent variables, you have the terms the wrong way round. I've seen that confusion often, and it's one of several reasons why -- if anything is outdated here -- the terminology of dependent and independent variables is top of the list.
Whether any effect of age is linear is a further question.

In addition, if the age distributions do not have a substantial overlap, correcting for age can simply remove the effect

First, as others have pointed out, ANOVA, ANCOVA and linear regression are equivalent. Mathematically, if there are $n$ observations and $p$ independent variables (or predictors, or whatever term you like), they are all
$$Y = XB + e, $$
where $Y$ is an $n \times 1$ vector of dependent variables (or response variables, or outcome, or whatever term you like), $X$ is an $n \times p$ matrix of independent variables, $B$ is a $p \times 1$ vector of parameters to be estimated and $e$ is an error vector.
The output from a program running these different procedures will look different, but they are all saying the same thing.
Second, I actually kind of like the terms "independent" and "dependent" variables. Maybe because all my work in stats was in fields where these terms are very common. But let's take your three variables: Age, group, and test score. Which could, logically, depend on which? Could you be older because you got a higher score? No. That's ludicrous. Could you be in a different group because you got a higher score? That's not quite as silly (depending on what the groups are and the experimental design) but it doesn't match the way you've described your study. If you were assigning groups based on test score, your initial question wouldn't make much sense. It would amount to something like "are tall people taller than short people?"
So, the IVs are age and group and the DV is score.

(+1) My objections (which are widely shared) to dependent and independent as terms include (1) they evidently aren't distinct enough, because people so often get them the wrong way round (2) the terms are overloaded (think also dependence in space or time or within blocks or groups) (3) there are more vivid alternatives. I don't mind much which alternatives people use, and it wouldn't matter if I did, but (e.g.) $XB$ in your notation is often called the predictor, a quite different usage.

@NickCox  I think English lacks really good terms for these concepts, and also lacks good terms for association rather than causation. E.g. If we are looking at height and weight, we would use height as the independent/predictor variable. But we can't (in an observational study) say "height causes weight"; we can say "height predicts weight" but we can also say "weight predicts height" which doesn't help with why weight should be on one side of the equation and height on the other.
But, this could easily get into a whole conversation (which we aren't supposed to have in comments).

What's the use of comments if you can't have a (focused) conversation too? Here I disagree in a friendly way. English has lots of good words: outcome, response, target; predictor, explanatory variable, covariate, feature; choose any of those or anything else, so long as you explain any idiosyncratic use. Similarly association, correlation and causation are among good words that help to impart precisely the nuanced distinction or discussion that one wants. I vote against regressand and regressor, FWIW.

Regarding conversations in comments, I agree. But then we will get that message about "moving comments to chat" which, to me, isn't a great option because it tends to leave out others. But ... That's the way StackExchange runs.

Indeed, but we haven't got to that point yet,

I like "covariate" because it doesn't have other meanings. "Predictor", to me, implies causation.
The problem with "association" and "correlation" is that they don't have a direction and, in regression, we are implying a direction of some sort. Just not "cause" exactly (unless it's an experiment).
Part of the problem is that the word "cause" is multifaceted and used in different but similar ways in different contexts. Sometimes it means "always" (rain makes the ground wet") other times not (smoking causes cancer).

(We have got to that point.)  I use covariate too because it's agnostic, but some want to insist on a covariate having a specific role in ANCOVA. There is not necessarily anything causal about prediction.  And as for association and correlation as terms not implying a direction, that's their essential advantage!  (You will recollect that Aristotle already 2500 years insisted that causes came in several different flavours.)

The other answers seem to already address the core question of which techniques to use. As others have mentioned, this seems to be a question that can be easily solved with regression or ANCOVA, and in principle neither is really a poor option. However with respect to the second option, while analysis of variance techniques are not "wrong", I nevertheless find a few major issues with how these techniques are taught and practiced, which promotes the following outcomes:

Because regression is often taught separate from ANOVA and its cousins, this often creates an illusion of limited choices. I have heard on a few occasions somebody say they have used ANCOVA because it "controls for covariates" while dismissing regression as a technique that can't. You sometimes see people bin continuous values to force their data to work for AN(C)OVA, which is neither necessary nor helpful. This is because people assume one can only work within the confines of the analysis of variance, whereas regression is far more flexible. Some even restrict their research designs in order to later use ANOVA and its cousins, which is problematic when we are after more complex models. Your data is already in hand, so this isn't really an issue in your case, but it can be when planning studies.
ANOVAs often encourage p-hacking because researchers commonly ritualize pairwise comparisons. To take an extreme example, consider if we are doing an ANOVA on the differences in sales between 500 gyms across the United States. Even if we don't have a terribly over-powered design, the $F$ test will often flag any minor discrepancy in the variance of the means because we have many knobs on the variance. Then one is left with 500 candidate group comparisons to deal with. Which do we actually care about? If our only goal is to see if there is ANY difference in means, the only thing we should care about is the ANOVA. If we truly care about specific group differences, then we would be better off looking at planned comparisons or just committing to a much more limited selection of groups. But because of highly ritualized behavior in the sciences, we check every t-test (despite having no specific hypotheses about these comparisons), and after we can craft a story about which ones are "correct" appraisals of an already flimsy hypothesis. Which comparisons actually mattered? Were they conceptualized beforehand? This often gets completely masked by bad practices brought on by ANOVA rituals.
Analysis of variance techniques require more annoying assumptions. For example, the sphericity assumption is often brought up in repeated measures ANOVA designs, yet is completely unnecessary to consider with respect to the same repeated measures in a linear mixed model (LMM) regression. When we scale up complexity to things like MANOVA, we get into more dangerous waters. We can't even deal with things like nonlinearities in ANCOVA in a useful way when covariates are not strictly linear.
Most importantly, the way ANOVA is taught contributes to "cookbook"-like thinking about statistical tests based on p-values. Because the ANOVA relies on an $F$ test and consequently $p$-values, this places the emphasis almost squarely on statistical significance as the primary barometer for success in a model. Even its post-hoc testing procedures rely squarely on PWCs which seem to be primarily about getting a conveniently low $p$-value. Consequently, and like many tests like it (chi-square, t-test, etc.), it ends up also being selected from a pile of several-named tests to achieve the same thing: find a very specific problem, search among many tests which works, and attach a $p$ value to it. Regression and the general linear model simply take a single idea...apply a linear model to some data, and adjust accordingly when the need for specificity arises (e.g. binary data -> logistic). Regressions are not immune to $p$ value problems (indeed, the coefficients and model both contain them), but I find less mental gymnastics in play with regressions given that there is a lot more people tend to consider ($R^2$, the coefficients, etc.).

Knowing all these things, one can apply ANCOVA to your problem without major issues, with the hopes that one respects things like the effect sizes, mean differences, confidence intervals, etc. As noted earlier, ANCOVA and regression give the exact same result anyway, given AN(C)OVA is just a special case of regression. One just has to keep in mind how instruction on analysis of variance techniques has historically promoted some bad practices.

This answer sums op several bad practices in statistics and blaims them on ANOVA. But just because ANOVA gets involved in those bad practices doesn't mean that it is because of ANOVA. Limited choices, p-hacking, assumptions and research designs tailored for those simple assumptions, cookbook thinking statistics. The reasons for those four points are that all scientists, including the ones that are not so great in mathematical thinking, have to learn statistics. Many people already struggle with statistics 101, and that is the reason that people use basic tests and approaches.

For the stated question (comparing two groups while removing the effect of a covariate) it doesn't matter at all whether an ANCOVA or a linear model (with OLS) is being used, they give the same result. You are describing the issues as if there is a difference in the results when you make this sentence „However with respect to the second option, while analysis of variance techniques are not "wrong", I nevertheless find a few major issues with these techniques “.

I have to disagree with the points you make here. How we teach these things shapes behavior, and even when taught "correctly", the idea of separating AN(C)OVA and regression as separate things contributes to this behavior (precisely because even Fisher didn't differentiate on that point). Not all of the bullets I have raised here are about bad practices either (which I still contend is because of how ANOVAs are framed). For example, my point about the assumptions of RM-ANOVA, even when people use it correctly, still remains an obstacle to their use.

"the idea of separating AN(C)OVA and regression as separate things contributes to this behavior (precisely because even Fisher didn't differentiate on that point)." Then it is teaching this separation what is a bad thing, not the analysis of variance. For teaching, I believe that analysis of variance is a great start, especially an approach that follows Fisher:...

... 1 With statistical methods for research workers, it shaped a thinking about within groups and between groups variation, and you can see it as some variant of a R^2 value and Cohen's later work on effect size (which always somehow compares the variations due to the effect with the variations due to the population
variability). Analysis of variance is a very simple and natural way of thinking about data (and a stepping stone to move towards mixed effects models)...

Do you think if I simply changed the wording of "I nevertheless find a few major issues with these techniques that are worthy of noting as problematic" to "I nevertheless find a few major issues with how these techniques are taught that are worthy of noting as problematic", this would resolve your problems with my answer?

... 2 with 'On a distribution yielding the error functions of several well known statistics' a thinking about error distributions in a more general sense is created and the F-distribution and ANOVA isninenif them. Whenever I think of linear models or t-tests, then often I have a geometrical view in my mind that relates to this general distribution. Examples of such geometric relations are in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358479/365070 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515874/516882

Using "issues with how these techniques are taught and practicised" would help a lot. Also, you could stress that for the case of the question the ANCOVA and regression (as in linear model with ordinary least squares), give the exact same result.

I have edited accordingly. I think your points make sense in any case, but felt that I needed to state my case for the record.
