Derivation for the probability density of the squared sum of k coordinates of a uniform distributed vector/point on a unit n-sphere

The distribution of a single coordinate of a uniform distributed vector/point on a n-sphere is beta distributed as argued here: Average absolute value of a coordinate of a random unit vector?

The distribution of the sum of squares of multiple coordinates of a uniform distributed vector/point on a n-sphere is also beta distributed.


I would like to try to similarly derive the second point in the same way as a proof for the first point.
Such proof will give a geometric approach to the derivation of an F-distribution, which can be linked to the squared sum of k coordinates of a uniform point on a n-sphere (Prove that F-statistic follows F-distribution).

This answer does a special case:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151854/a-normal-divided-by-the-sqrt-chi2s-s-gives-you-a-t-distribution-proof/151969#151969

I can imagine an n-ball as a sum of (n-1)-balls and that is how the first point is derived. But now I am trying to contemplate the n-ball as a sum of k-balls.

@StevenGubkin that's the t-distribution which is the root of a F(1,n) distribution and relates to that first case in the question. But it is a good reference that I will add later to the question. It is the geometric reasoning that I am looking for.

@SextusEmpiricus perhaps the Geoff Hinton (topical!) approach: to picture it for $k=14$, picture it for $k=1$ and firmly say "fourteen" to yourself.

@ThomasLumley do you have a reference?

Slide 16 here: https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/coursera/lecture2/lec2.pptx

@ThomasLumley I use that technique often, imagine 3d, then change to higher dimensions. So here I imagine slicing a 3-ball by constraining k dimensions into 3-k balls, then use it for slicing n-balls into n-k balls. For the case k=1 I can imagine those slices in 3d, but for k>1, those slices are difficult to imagine also in 3d.

The following closely follows whuber's exposition of deriving the t-distribution here.
It comes down to parameterizing the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{d_1 + d_2}$ by using a point on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{d_1}$, a point on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{d_2}$, and an angle $\theta$.  Quick dimension check:  $d_1 + d_2 -1 = (d_1 - 1) + (d_2 - 1) + 1$.  Then the formula boils down to pulling back the uniform density on the unit sphere in $R^{d_1 + d_2}$ along this parameterization.  You don't even need to integrate since we know how volumes of $d$ dimensional spheres should scale as a function of the radii!
Without further ado:
Let $ X \in \mathbb{R}^{d_1 + d_2} $ be normally distributed as $ N(0, I_{d_1 + d_2}) $. Define:

$ X_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{d_1} $: projection of $ X $ onto the first $ d_1 $ coordinates.
$ X_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{d_2} $: projection of $ X $ onto the last $ d_2 $ coordinates.

The squared norms of $ X_1 $ and $ X_2 $, $ |X_1|^2 $ and $ |X_2|^2 $, are independent chi-squared random variables with $ d_1 $ and $ d_2 $ degrees of freedom, respectively.
The random vector $ U = \frac{X}{|X|} $ is uniformly distributed on the unit sphere $ S^{d_1 + d_2 - 1} $.  Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be its projections onto the first $d_1$ last and $d_2$ coordinates respectively.
Let $ \theta $ be the angle between $ X_1 $ and $ X_2 $.
Then
$$
U_1 = \sin(\theta) \, V_1, \quad U_2 = \cos(\theta) \, V_2
$$
where:

$ V_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{d_1} $ is a unit vector on the $ d_1 $-dimensional unit sphere, and
$ V_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{d_2} $ is a unit vector on the $ d_2 $-dimensional unit sphere.

The angle $ \theta $ lies in $ [0, \frac{\pi}{2}] $, controlling the relative sizes of $ |U_1| $ and $|U_2| $.
The ratio of interest is $ \frac{|U_1|^2}{|U_2|^2} $, which simplifies in these spherical coordinates to $ \frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)} = \tan^2(\theta) $.
Thus, $ \tan^2(\theta) $ is proportional to an $F$-distribution. The pdf of $ \tan^2(\theta) $ is the $ F_{d_1, d_2} $ distribution.
To find the pdf of the $ F $-distribution, we need to compute the volume element in this spherical coordinate system. The volume element on the unit sphere is proportional to:
$$
dV \propto (\sin(\theta))^{d_1 - 1} (\cos(\theta))^{d_2 - 1} \, d\theta
$$
since these are the radii of $d_1 - 1$ and $d_2 - 1$ dimensional spheres.
Letting $T = \tan^2(\theta)$ we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\sin^2(\theta) &= \frac{T}{1-T}\\
\cos^2(\theta) &= \frac{1}{1-T}\\
d\theta &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{T}} \, \frac{dT}{1+T}
\end{align*}
$$
Using this and the volume element, the pdf of $ T $ can be expressed as:
$$
f_T(T) \propto \frac{T^{\frac{d_1}{2} - 1}}{(1 + T)^{\frac{d_1 + d_2}{2}}}
$$
This is proportional to the pdf of the $ F $-distribution.
Remember that $T = \frac{|U_1|^2}{|U_2|^2}$ but we really wanted $Y = \frac{|U_1|^2/d_1}{|U_2|^2/d_2}$ which is $F_{d_1,d_2}$ distributed "on the nose".  Substituting $T = \frac{d_1}{d_2} Y$ we get
$$
f_F(y) \propto \frac{y^{\frac{d_1}{2} - 1}}{\left(1 + \frac{d_1}{d_2} y\right)^{(d_1 + d_2)/2}}
$$

"To find the pdf of the F-distribution, we need to compute the volume element in this spherical coordinate system." This section is the key step for me. I am doing the same approach in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305875/average-absolute-value-of-a-coordinate-of-a-random-unit-vector with the image https://i.sstatic.net/2lCEI.png to compute the area/volume for the frustum. Except in terms of dx instead of dtheta. Using an angle will solve the problem with the one-dimensional dx that I had. I still wonder about simply multiplying the two differential areas.

@SextusEmpiricus The volume of a product of two sets is the product of the volumes.  For instance, the volume of a cylinder is the area of the base times the height.

Yes, in the related image we also eventually have a product $A_{slice} = A_{n-2} \times ds$. I still have to get to visualise that $ds$ as being replaced by the change in the area of a unit sphere. I trust that your answer is the solution, but it this step that doesn't fall into place entirely yet.
