# Does the distribution $f(x) \propto (1-x^2)^{n/2}$ have a name?

Tags: distributions, terminology, beta-distribution, definition, geometry

The distribution  $f(x) \propto (1-x^2)^{n/2}$ for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$

- It occurs in a problem like [Law of the norm of the empirical mean of uniforms on the sphere?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/499562/)
- It relates to intersections of high dimensional sphere. See the image from this question: [Volumes of n-balls: what is so special about n=5?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15656/volumes-of-n-balls-what-is-so-special-about-n-5/2903950#2903950)
  [image: integrand]
- It is the distribution of a coordinate of point that is uniform distributed on a sphere: [Average absolute value of a coordinate of a random unit vector?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305875)

Comment: In this answer by Whuber it seems to be simply a scaled and shifted beta distribution https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/169818

Comment: A transform into $y=(1+x)/2$ leads to a standard Beta $Y\sim\mathcal B(1+n/2,1+n/2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known as a **Power semi-circle** distribution with pdf $f(x)$:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\frac{\Gamma (\theta +2) }{ \Gamma \left(\theta +\frac{3}{2}\right)} \sqrt{1-x^2}^{2 \theta +1} \quad \quad \text{for } -1 < x < 1$$

... where shape parameter $\theta > -\frac{3}{2}$, and where your parameter $n = 2 \theta + 1$.

[image]

It nests a number of known distributions including:

- ArcSine(-1,1) $\quad$ if $\theta = -1$
- Uniform(-1,1) $\quad$ if $\theta = -\frac12$
- Semicircle(-1,1) $\quad$ if $\theta = 0$
- Epanechnikov kernel $\quad$ if $\theta = \frac12$
- Bi-weight kernel $\quad$ if $\theta = \frac32$
- Tri-weight kernel $\quad$ if $\theta = \frac52$

A reference is:

Kingman, J. F. C. (1963), Random walks with spherical symmetry, *Acta Mathematica*, 109(1), 11-53.

Answer (score 3):

This distribution is a scaled and shifted beta distribution. This can be seen by rewriting $t=0.5+0.5x$ or $x = 2t-1$ such that  $1-x^2 = 4 t(1-t)$